# What does [^ab]* match with a?

Tags: python, regex

I just learnt that [^ab] will catch any character other than a or b.
So [^ab]* should match 0 or more characters none of which are a or b.

Yet python somehow matches [^ab]* to a.

```
pattern = '[^ab]*'
str = 'a'
r = re.compile(pattern)
m = r.match(str)
if m is None:
    print 'No match'
else:
    print 'match'
```

This code snippet prints a match. I believe either I am wrong in understanding the usage of ^ or made some error in the code

Comment: It matches 0 characters, none of which are a or b.

Comment: So how is the 'a' being matched?

Comment: It's `*` that's confusing you, not `^`.

Comment: You may be thinking of the semantics of `fullmatch` rather than `match`.

Comment: @melpomene Don't you mean "all of which"? ;-)

Comment: okay, so * matches with 0 characters, none of which are a or b, this means [^ab]* should match with an empty string. What is the part in pattern that is matching with 'a' in str

Comment: @user3828311 None.

Comment: @user3828311: It's *not* matching the `a`. It's matching the empty leading substring of your string.

Comment: OP, perhaps you mean to use `[^ab][^ab]*` or maybe `^[^ab]*$` (no doubt there are other possibilities as well). For some regex implementations you can say `[^ab]+` to mean 1 or more; I don't remember if Python regex recognizes that.

Comment: Visual: https://regex101.com/

Comment: The best way to avoid this is to use anchor points `^` and `$` whenever possible, especially when using the `*` quantifier. `^[^ab]*$` will not match `a` because it will have to start at the beginning of the string and go all the way to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]*` means **zero** or more instances of what is in the brackets. In this case the empty string is matched since it is part of your string.

See [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), section **match**.

> If **zero** or more characters **at the beginning** of string match the regular expression pattern...

The string `'a'` has the empty string `''` at the beginning if you will. You could say the reg ex is seeing it as `''+'a'` where the beginning matches your pattern.

Maybe you want to try fullmatch instead.

Comment: Okay I understand what [^ab]* matches an empty string from str. What is being matched with 'a' from str

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood the difference between match and full match.
so match will match any part of str, full match makes sure the entire str matches the pattern right ?

Comment: No, `match` will match the **start** of a string, see the quote from the docs in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `"a"` isn't the one being matched, it's an empty string (`""`) that's being matched.

As you know, the `*` in regex signifies that the previous group matches 0 or more times - your regex is matching `[^ab]` 0 times, which is an empty string. Because of this, `m` is not `None`, but contains the empty string, which is different from no match.

I wrote the assignments into a REPL:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '[^ab]*'
>>> str = 'a'
>>> r = re.compile(pattern)
>>> m = r.match(str)
>>> m.groups()
=> ()
>>> m.group(0)
=> ''
>>> m.group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: no such group
```

You can see that `m.groups()` is an empty tuple (and therefore not None), and `m.group(0)` returns an empty string, which means `pattern` matched `1` item (since `m.group(1)` doesn't work), which is an empty string.

Try using `[^ab]+` to not match anything - the `+` is like `*`, but it matches at least once.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers states, using `*` regex expression matches **0** or more matches. *That's the tricky part.*

You can do some testing, and better understand how Python treats `*`. The *match object* has the groups() method which returns the matches in groups:

```
>>> r.match(str_).groups()
()
```

This seems odd. How come this returns an empty group? This is even more strange: the findall method returns a list of matched items

```
>>> r.findall(str_)
['', '']
```

Two empty strings. This means even when there is no match, you'll get an empty item (list / tuple). If you change the `*` to `+` (match one or more) the results are different:

```
>>> pattern = '[^ab]+'
>>> re.match(pattern, 'a').groups()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#135>", line 1, in <module>
    re.match(pattern, 'a').groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

This returns `None`.

So, to sum it up, Python treats `*` with additional *empty string* at the beginning of the searched string when used in pattern such `[]*`. However, when the pattern `[]+` is used it doesn't do that.